# Quiero realizar que la variable result me arrogue un valor puede ser 0 o mayor a 0

Tags: php, pdo, variables

Creo que no estoy no estoy utilizando bien la variable  $result. Ya que la idea es que me arrogue 0 o usuarios mayor a 0.

PD. Mas que la consulta el uso correcto de la variable $result

require_once 'conexion.php';

```
  $db = new Database();
  $conection = $db->conectar();

  $query = $conection->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (nombres = ? AND id_usuario != ?) OR (email = ? AND id_usuario != ?) ");

  $query->execute([$_POST['nombres'], $_POST['id_usuario'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['id_usuario']]);
  $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ($result > 0) {
     setcookie("error",1);
     header("Location: usuarios_lista01.php");
  }else{
     
     
        setcookie("add",1);
        header("Location: usuarios_lista02.php");
     
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Me voy a auto responder.

Mi error estaba en esta línea: `$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Lo cambie por esta línea: `$result = $query->rowCount();`

[rowCount()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php): devuelve el número de filas afectadas por la última sentencia SQL